# Running sequential command line arguments from python and retrieving output

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I've been banging my head against the wall long enough, throwing in the towel here.
I am trying to use Python (specifically 3.8.2) to interface with a tool that has an ugly command line interface. I have the below command, which works. However, I've been reading up and it seems like this is a deprecated method, and they recommend using `subprocess.run` now. I've been trying convert my code over and having a lot of trouble, so hoping to find some help. Code below, along with an explanation.

```
os.system(rf'cmd /k "{ExecDrive}: & cd {ExecDirectory} & {command}"')
```

The first part of this is changing the drive letter and directory to a place where the programs executable is stored. Given a user could run this from any location, I have to ensure that they are in the right directory before running the command in the f-string below (which is essentially `targetApp.exe -Arg1 Val1 -Arg2 Val2` etc.).

Second, I need to capture the output so I can parse it for some messages. I think I can figure that part out on my own if I can get the first part working, but if you're a `subprocess.run` pro, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What operating system are you talking about (I assume windows)? can you give a little more background as to what the inputs and outputs to the executable are and  where in relationship to the executable directory you expect your inputs and outputs to be? is your executable path static?

Comment: Yes, windows. Input is just a large string (see example above) of parameters. Output will just be the lines that the app writes to the console window; specifically, the app writes out a few lines that  I need to capture and parse, looking for a specific string. Inputs will be directly in code, outputs will be in the console window (assuming stdout will work).

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to use the `cwd` command to accomplish what I needed. The new code is below.
`subprocess.run(command, cwd=rf"{ExecDrive}:{ExecDirectory}", shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

There is

```
subprocess.check_output(args)
```

for capturing output.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output